Wifi slower than on Windows
I have the following problem. Using Wifi my internet Speed is around 300-320mbps on windows. In linux it's 80-100mbps. I tried to set 11n_disable to different values and nothing changed (maybe I am doing it wrong but I don't think so).
Switching Kernels did also not help.
If anybody has any advice or needs more info please tell as I am not very used to linux.
I am running Kubuntu 24.04 with the xanmod kernel. This issue also occurs on gnome Ubuntu.
iwconfig output:
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"****"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: *HIDDEN*   
          Bit Rate=413 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:171   Missed beacon:0

lshw -C network output:
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 1a
       serial: f4:ce:23:08:02:8c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.9.9-x64v4-xanmod1 firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-86.uc ip=192.168.178.154 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:35 memory:fca00000-fca03fff


Is that the kernel the the OS came with? You show a couple of bad numbers in your post. Here is one from the network interface Invalid misc:171

I am running the xanmod kernel currently to fix some other issues I had with audio. But the xanmod loads the same driver as the default kernel so this should be identical. I will add the same output with the default one
